# The Hashtable type in C# is implemented using chaining or open addressing?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If open addressing, how is the probe sequence generated. pls give links

Comment: Hashtable or Dictionary?

Comment: I would lay money on it using chaining.  Effective open addressing usually requires two hashing functions, whereas objects in the CLR can only guarantee to provide one (GetHashCode()).  Moreover, deleting from a hash table using open addressing is a pain.  There are related schemes, but chaining isn't that much of an issue in practice (certainly not according to the benchmarks that I ran a few years back).

Answer (score 5):

It uses open addressing (or as we used to say, "closed hashing") with double hashing to generate the probe address sequence.  GetHashCode() determines the first probe index; the interval is also a function of GHC().

You can see this for yourself, if you step into the source code of System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(), for example. [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/].

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

Hashtable in .net framework is using open addressing or Double Hashing technique while Dictionary is using Chaining as a collision avoidence technique.

[See this link @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms379571.aspx)